# How to save dynamically created structs in an array with proper memory management?

Tags: c, struct

I would like to create structs in a loop and pass them to a function `foo`. This function then is supposed to process the struct data and save the struct in an array for later reuse.

```
// create structs in a loop
for(int i=0; i<1000); i++) {
    my_struct* s = (my_struct*) malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    s->memb1 = "foo"; // this data will change in each iteration
    s->memb2 = "bar"; // only for simplicity here

    store_in_array(s);
}

// ...
my_struct* global_array = (my_struct*) malloc(size * sizeof(my_struct));

int foo(my_struct* s) {

    // process s in some way
    // ...

    // store s it for later use in array
    global_array[index] = s; // boom
}
```

1. Obviously this way of storing is not possible, because I cannot save the pointer to a `s` in the array. However, I do not know how to do it. How does it work?
2. The loop will overwrite the s pointer in the next iteration. I do not want the data in `global_array` to change. How can I achieve this? Do I need to create a deep copy of `s` in `foo`?
3. Later on I won't make use of `global_array` and I would like to free the memory. Does it suffice to simply call `free(global_array)` to free the actual content, i.e. all structs that I've stored in it beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep track of the pointers, your global array should not be an array of `my_struct`, as you have it set up, but an array of `my_struct *`.

```
// don't cast the return value of malloc
my_struct **global_array = malloc(size * sizeof(my_struct *));
      //  ^---- note the placement of ** with the variable instead of the type name
      // this reduces ambiguity
```

Then you can add to the array like this, assuming `index` is the current size of the array:

```
global_array[index++] = s;
```

Then when you clean up, you first `free` each array member, then the array itself:

```
int i;
for (i=0 i<index; i++) {
    free(global_array[i]);
}
free(global_array);
```

Comment: There is no problem when overwriting the pointer in the next loop iteration? The allocated memory still exists, but there is no memory leak, because I save the pointer in the array. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct.  You pass the pointer value to a function which saves it in the global array, so no leak.  As long as you `free` the global list in the end, you're fine.

Comment: @null - Also note that this solution only works up to a fixed number, `size`, entries in the array.  So you either need to make sure that `index` never goes past the end of the array --OR-- use `realloc` to grow your array when it does.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have outlines is basically sound (the declaration of the global array is incorrrect).

To answer your questions.
1. Yes, you can store the pointer s in the array.
2. The data stored in the global array will not change. You may not need to make a deep copy (I can't say for sure because you don't show you plan to assign values to memb1 and memb2).
3. You will need to free each element of the array and then free the array.

As a previous answer has stated, the declaration of the global array is incorrect, it should be something like:

```
my_struct** global_array = (my_struct**) malloc(size * sizeof(my_struct *));
```

The cast of the pointer returned by malloc is optional, and I assume size is equal to 1000.

Answer (score -1):

To save a pointer in the array, you need to use array of pointers. Something like this:

```
// Notice no cast from malloc
my_struct** global_array = malloc(size * sizeof(my_struct*));
```

This will require you to free the pointers to objects before you free the array. Like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size, ++i)
    free(global_array[i]);
free(global_array);
```